# Laravel GroupBy and Count using eloquent model

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table

`'new_comments'`

with fields

`id,user_id,
title,
comment_description`

I have another table named

`'comments_upvote'`

having

`field user_id, 
post_id, 
likes`

id of new_comments and post_id of comments_upvote table are same. we have to take those comments which have the most likes. how we fetch that data.

```
$ud = Comments_upvote::select('post_id')->groupby('post_id')- 
>orderby(DB::raw('count(likes)'), 'desc')->get();
$postid = array();
  foreach ($ud as $key => $value) {

    $postid[] = $value->post_id;
  }
 $data = DB::table('new_comments')->whereIn('id',$postid)->get();
```

but the problem is that i have to count all likes whose value = 1 how can we do that.

Comment: Please, show an example of what you expect

Comment: Please, extend explanation with examples, and show answer found, in order to hep someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you showed us some code you'd get a more concrete answer, but here's a quick outline of what you need: define your relationships (make sure you use your custom foreign key), use whereHas, group by post_id count, and sort by count descending.

So I'm guessing you have at least two models NewComment and CommentUpvote (you should). In the NewComment define a 1:n relationship:

```
public function upvotes(){
    $this->hasMany('App\CommentUpvote', 'post_id');
}
```

Then in your controller (again, guessing, since you didn't show any code):

```
$bestComments = NewComment::whereHas('upvotes', function($query){
  $query->select('post_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('post_id')->orderBy('total', 'desc');
})->get();
```

Disclaimer: this is untested and off the top of my head, but should nugde you in the right direction.